# Three Different Regression Results... Why is one so weak compared to the other two?

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, descriptive-statistics, r-squared

I have a data set I'm working with, it's roughly 450K rows of data. I'm breaking the data out from a certain column, and that column has three results. After that, I ran a regression analysis for each to determine the correlation between to variables. The results came as such:

A: 0.91
B: 0.39
C: 0.86

So as you can see, for A and C, it had a very strong correlation. But for B, it was much lower (by the way, for the entire data set, without breaking them out by the three, the R-Squared was a 0.88).

What can I do to deeper investigate why the relationships were so strong in A and C but not B?

Comment: I am a bit confused by the wording of your issue. You have data in a column, but can that column only contain 3 unique values?

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify. The Excel document is roughly 450K rows of data with eight columns. In one of those columns, there are three different outcomes (non-numerical) that I'm trying to analyze. Lets just call it subscription type A, B, and C. In another two of those columns, there are results. Those two variables and using to run the regression analysis. Hopefully that helps clear it up.